# Primes congruent to a mod n.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic, distribution-of-primes

Is there at least one prime **p** that is congruent to **a mod n**, where **n** can be any positive integer and **a** can be any non-negative integer less than **n**?

Comment: well, if $\gcd(a,n) = 1,$ yes.

Comment: See [Dirichlet's Theorem on Primes in Arithmetic Progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)

Comment: for example, there is no prime $p \equiv 15 \pmod {30}$

Comment: So is there a result that establishes in which cases of a and n there is no prime p that satisfies the congruence?

Comment: @user343996 If $a=0$ , then there is no such prime, if $n$ is composite. If $a\ne 0$  and $\gcd(a,n)\ne 1$, then there is no such prime, if $a$ is composite.

Answer (score 2):

The complete answer is given by the different comments:

If $(a,n)=1$ then there are infinite primes that satisfy the equation $p=a$ mod $n$. This is the content of the Dirichlet's theorem on arithmetic progressions.  Moreover, the primes are evenly distributed (asymptotically) among the congruence classes modulo $n$ containing the $a$'s coprime to $n$.

If $(a,n)>1$, we can have to cases:

1) If $a$ is prime, then we only have the trivial solution $p=a$.

Proof: If $a$ is prime and $(a,n)>1$ then $a$ is a factor of $n$, so $n=ab$ for some positive integer $b$, so the equation can be written $p = a$ mod $ab$, meaning $p$ = $a + (ab)c$ for some integer $c$. Then $p = a(1+bc)$, but $a$ is prime, so there is only one solution, namely when $c=0$.

2) If $a$ is composite, then there are no solutions.

Proof: $p = a$ mod $n$, means $p$ = $a + nI$ for some integer $I$, let's define $J=nI$ so now $p$ = $a + J$. Now, since $a$ and $n$ are not coprime, the same applies for $a$ and $J$, so by Bézout's identity: $aA+JB=C$ where $C > 1$ is the **gcd** of $a$ and $J$, and $A$ and $B$ are non-zero integers. Then $p$ = $a + ((C-aA)/B)$. And since $C$ is a factor of $a$ we have $p=CD + ((C-CDA)/B)$ for some positive integer $D$. Then $p=C(1+((1-DA)/B)$. Now, because $C>1$, for $p$ to be prime we need $(1+((1-DA)/B)$ to be equal to $1$, so $(1-DA)$ needs to be zero. But we said that $D$ is a positive integer, so $A$ has to be zero. But we said that $A$ is non-zero integer, we can conclude then that $p$ cannot be prime.

Comment: Just one note: this solution assumes $a\leq n$; we have for example at $a=6$ and $n=4$ the prime $p=2\equiv 6\bmod 4$. Another way to put it: for any $a$ where $\gcd(a,n)>1$ all values $m\equiv a\bmod n$ so that $m>n$ are composite.

Comment: Thank you, I always thought that the congruence equations assumed that $a≤n$. I will edit the question so that this is explicit.