# What is the GCD of a prime and a composite?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I am reading a paper<sup>[0](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Rui-Xue-7/publication/220271944_Universal_Accumulators_with_Efficient_Nonmembership_Proofs/links/0046353c3c2eebe493000000/Universal-Accumulators-with-Efficient-Nonmembership-Proofs.pdf?origin=publication_detail)</sup> that states

> Also observe that, the number of x ∈ X_k such that gcd(x, u') != 1 is less than k, as x must be a prime.

Here, k is the size of the set X; u' = u mod phi(N) where phi(N) is the prime factorization of N=p*q; and u is a composite (the product of a set of primes).

I am trying to understand the cases in which gcd(x,u') != 1. Here is my thought process:

A prime x only has two divisors, 1 and x. This means that gcd(x,?) will always be either 1 or x.

Since u is always composite, u' = u mod phi(N) must also be composite<sup>[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3078479/153292)</sup>. If u' is composite then x != u' and therefore gcd(x,u') must be 1.

Is my reasoning correct?

(Apologies for the formatting—I am on a mobile device.)

Comment: For any prime $p$ and any integer $n$, the gcd of $p$ and $n$ is $p$ if $p \mid n$ and $1$ otherwise.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang sorry, I’m not sure how to parse "p | n".

Comment: $p|n$ means p divides n (i.e. $p$ is a divisor of $n$).

Comment: @StevenClark Thank you! Googling the symbol didn’t help much.

Comment: So it looks like I was partially correct, I just missed the (important) case where u > p. And now I think “less than k” makes sense!

Comment: the gcd must in particular divide the prime number. There are not many possibilities :)

Comment: @Peter this was a case of me overly doubting my intuition because I did not want to make a mistake :)